# fetch table column in case else statement in pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Query correctly fetches `student_id` in TRUE condition but it does not fetch `(max(gr_number)+1)` in else condition. Below is my query, please help me out.

```
 Select case when count(*) > 0 then student_id else (max(gr_number)+1) end student_id
 from student 
 where student_name ='faizan ahmed' 
 and email_id='abc@gmail.com' 
 and UPPER(student_dob)=UPPER('01-FEB-19') 
 and  rownum = 1 
 group by student_id, gr_number  ;
```

It returns null in else condition .

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should not store DATE values in VARCHAR columns. The condition `UPPER(student_dob)=UPPER('01-FEB-19')` suggests that `student_dob` is a varchar column - don't do that. Use a proper `DATE` column

Answer (score 2):

The FALSE condition is when `count()`is not greater than zero. So it's FALSE when **no records have been found**. Consequently NULL is the correct result, because `gr_number` is null (no records found) so `max(gr_number)` is null and `max(gr_number)+1` is null.

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but here is one solution which will return a value if you don't find the specific student:

```
Select coalesce(s.student_id, g.gr_number+1) as student_id
from (select 1 as rn, max(gr_number) as gr_number
      from student ) g
left outer join
      ( select rownum as rn, student_id
        from student
        where student_name ='faizan ahmed' 
        and email_id='abc@gmail.com' 
        and UPPER(student_dob)=UPPER('01-FEB-19') 
        and  rownum = 1 ) s
 on s.rn = g.rn
  ;
```

Comment: Did you unaccept this answer because you've asked a new question? If so, poor show.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the maximum `gr_number` per student, you shouldn't group by it, only by the student id:

```
group by student_id;
```